# Firestore database reads are increasing without even running the application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been noticing some increase in the amount of reads in the firestore. I am testing my application on localhost.

Today I decided to have a closer look at the amount of reads and started from zero. I waited around 3 minutes without even running my application or performing any read operation, and my number of reads went up to 210, and 2 writes. Now that must be pretty weird, knowing that the application wasn't even running and it was all zero when I started.

I tried to avoid the onvalueChanges() and snapshotChanges() since they generate a lot of read.

Below is the service that I call in the home page.

Any one has an idea on what's going on, and would like to share?

Thanks in advance.

```
 export class CatService {
 lastVisibleCat: any;
 cats = [];
 fecha = new Date().setHours(23, 59, 5, 9);
 todaysDate = new Date(this.fecha);


   constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
  }

getCats() {
const reference = this.afs.collection('Cats');
const query1 = reference.ref.where('timeStampEndDate', '>=', 
this.todaysDate);
return query1.get().then(snapShot => {
  snapShot.forEach(cat => {
    this.cats.push({ ...cat.data(), id: cat.id });
  });
  return this.cats;
});
}

  }
```

Comment: I encounter same issue without any usage `reads` has 400 per hour, I don't have any application using on cloud and local, and no firebase console open. I even refresh api key, still accumulates, no clue

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things could be at play here:

- Read counts are not real time, so the data could be coming in delayed
- Reads in the Firebase Console also count towards billed operations in terms of read counts

Comment: yeah actually i am keeping my console open whenever I am coding, and every time I check the collection the amount of read goes up, so it is because of that for sure.
But what i don't understand is why is the number more than the documents i have?
I literally have 11 documents in the first collection and 1 document in the second, and every time i am in the console it is increasing by 58 reads which I dont get where this number is coming from. It is supposed to be read per document.

Comment: That's harder for me to answer, if you write into support they *might* be able to give you exact numbers, but the reads are per client so 1 for the console and 1 for the app, which is 24, and the console maybe doing more because it actually does 2 queries, one to fetch the collections and then another for individual documents, then if you do any updates to those documents the console has a realtime snapshot listener, which each update sent is counted as a read as well